# MVC3 Razor IIS 7 background process timing out

Tags: c#, iis, razor, timeout

I have an MVC3 razor page that essentially does this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Mymodel model)
{
//run background process
return(model);
}
public backgroundprocesscompleted()
{
//write to database
}
```

The run background process part runs an analysis via a library then once it is done runs backgroundprocesscompleted.  This whole thing works for small files (46 rows) but when I do it on bigger files (11k) it runs on IIS and appears to time out.  I have changed numerous settings but still it times out.  Essentially what I would like to do is force the web application to never timeout.  Any good ideas on how to fix this?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several reasons why a longer-running background process in ASP.Net might fail, including

- An unhandled exception in a thread not associated with a request will take down the process.
- The AppDomain your site runs in can go down for a number of reasons and take down your background task with it.
- When you modify web.config, ASP.NET will recycle the AppDomain
- IIS will itself recycle the entire w3wp.exe process every 29 hours (by default)
- In a shared hosting environment, many web servers are configured to tear down the application pools after some period of inactivity

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

The article linked above has some suggestions for mitigating those risks.  However, I would recommend doing long-running processing entirely outside of ASP.Net.  One straightforward approach is to write the work into a transactional MSMQ Queue, and have a Windows Service read work items off of that queue and process them.

Comment: WCF also runs in the context of IIS (usually, unless you create/use a different host) and runs into the same issues.